# is there an elegant number button for IOS on XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Using xamarin forms to build an app....Finding plenty of examples on '`elegant number button` ' for android but none for ios? does one exist?

Thanks

Comment: You can mark the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a [Stepper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/views#stepper) control